# Trying to make a POST request with Postman but nothing happens (NestJS and TypeORM)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to make a simple `POST request` but there isn't any feedback and the new data isn't going to the database (Postgres). I am using NestJS and TypeORM. When I try to make a `GET request` everything is fine. I am new to Postman, but I couldn't find any help on the internet...

Postman POST request (I tried it with only username and password too):

```
{
    "id": 11,
    "username": "proba11",
    "password": "proba11",
    "method": 1,
    "status": "ACTIVE"
}
```

The entity schema with TypeORM:

```
@Entity({ name: "user_user" })
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ unique: true })
  username: string;

  @Column()
  password: string;

  @Column()
  method: number;

  @Column()
  status: UserStatus;

  @CreateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  createdat: number;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: "timestamp" })
  updatedat: number;
}
```

The controller:

```
@Post()
async create(@Res() resp: Response, @Body() user: User) {
 const ret = await this.userService.save(user);
 resp.status(ret).send();
  }
```

And finally the save function of the Service:

```
hash1(password: string): string {
    var newpass = password + pepper;
    const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
    return bcrypt.hashSync(sha3_512(newpass, undefined), salt);
  }

async save(user: User): Promise<number> {
    try {
      user.status = UserStatus.ACTIVE;
      user.method = 1;
      user.password = this.hash1(user.password);
      await this.userRepositroy.save(user);
      return HttpStatus.OK;
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof QueryFailedError) return HttpStatus.CONFLICT;
      this.logger.error(e);
      return HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    }
  }
```

I hope you guys can help :)

Comment: Show me your headers in postman

Comment: @A.khalifa There isn't any special header. I only edited the raw of Body.

Comment: Try to add this header content-type: application/json in your postman

Comment: @A.khalifa Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, I will write answer depends our discussion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add header in Postman to accept json like below :

```
"Content-Type": "application/json"
```

Hope useful for you